# Reading packets from a client stops after 1 or 2 received

Tags: c, linux, sockets, server

I'm writing a server program in C that will read commands from the client. Commands are in the form of 5 byte packets, and the client will be sending a bunch of them in succession. The code I have to read each command is:

```
while(1)
{
    char buffer[1024];
    int alreadyread = 0;
    int socket = dequeue();

    while(alreadyread != 5)
    {
        do
        {
            nowread = read(socket,buffer+alreadyread,5-alreadyread);
            alreadyread += nowread;
        }
        while((nowread > 0) && (5-alreadyread > 0));

        if(nowread == -1 || nowread == 0)
        {
            printf("Error reading from client socket\n");
            exit(1);
        }
              //DO COMMAND
```

But this doesn't seem to work: if the client sends 10 packets, I read 1 or 2 and then get a segfault. Does anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `while (alreadyread != 5)` seems extraneous since `alreadyread` will be 5 or `nowread` will be less than 0 after the do-while, and if `nowread` is less than 0 you exit.

You've poorly defined a command, I think we need more information on that.

It looks like you're getting a new socket after each command. If it's just one client sending commands, you should keep the socket until you get all the commands you want. You should also `close` the socket after you are done with it so you don't run out of file descriptors.

The segfault is likely caused by another area of your program which you haven't shown.